# Can "drush make" command use cached temporary files?

Tags: drush

With Drush 6.2.0, after using

```
$ drush make build_my_project.make my_project/
```

more than once, it results in

> ..
>   Found makefile: drupal-org.make
>   Install location /private/tmp/make_tmp/profiles/openhotel/modules/contrib/omega_tools already exists. **Do you want to overwrite it? (y/n): y**
>   omega_tools-7.x-3.0-rc4 downloaded.    ...

which means the module already exists in

> /private/tmp/make_tmp

I tried to force **assuming no** to all questions

```
$ drush make build_my_project.make my_project/ --no
```

which doesn't work, it still answers yes to all questions. How can I avoid downloading all projects every time I make a build?

Comment: Please specify the version of drush you are using. From what I can remember the later versions of drush cache projects on a per user basis.

Comment: The version of Drush is 6.2.0.